# Scrapy / ignore empty items

Tags: python, scrapy

I've made this small bot which processes through a list of search parameters. It works fine until there are several results on the page: `product_prices_euros` gives a list of items where half are empty. So when I concatenate with `product_prices_cents`, I have an output like the following:

```
  'price' : '',76
```

for half results. Is there a simple way to prevent empty items for being collected? My output for `product_prices_euros` looks like:

```
[' 1', ' ', ' 2', ' ', ' 2', ' ', ' 1', ' ', ' 1', ' ', ' 1', ' ', ' 2', ' ']
```

I'd like to keep only '1', '2', etc...

Here is what looks like CSS. There might be something on this side :

```
< span class="product-pricing__main-price" >
2 
< span class="cents" >,79€< /span >
< /span >
```

And my code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    base_url="https://new.carrefour.fr/s?q="
    test_file = open(r"example", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(test_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            url = row[0]
            absolute_url = base_url+url
            print(absolute_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301]}, callback=self.parse)


def parse(self, response):
    product_name = response.css("h2.label.title::text").extract()
    product_packaging = response.css("div.label.packaging::text").extract()
    product_price_euros = response.css("span.product-pricing__main-price::text").extract()
    product_price_cents = response.css("span.cents::text").extract()
    for name, packaging, price_euro, price_cent in zip(product_name, product_packaging, product_price_euros, product_price_cents):
            yield { 'ean' : response.css("h1.page-title::text").extract(), 'name': name+packaging, 'price': price_euro+price_cent}
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just filter the empty *euro* elements, how could you match them to their proper *cents*?

First, IMHO I think it would be easier if you loop over the products to collect their data. Eg.

```
for product in response.css('.product-list__item'):
    name = product.css("h2.label.title::text").extract()
    # ...
```

Thus, you could get the prices and cents like this:

```
>>> product.css('.product-pricing__main-price  ::text')
['2', ',99€']

>>> ''.join(product.css('.product-pricing__main-price  ::text').getall())
'2,99€'
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this ! Thank you

Comment: Your solution works until I try to include it into a zip... Here is a question I posted about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173482/scrapy-get-result-in-shell-but-not-in-script/53173734#53173734
If you have a clean solution by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end you can filter your list by the occurrences you don't want:

`list(filter(lambda a: a != '', yourList))`

Comment: Like this ? 

product_price_euros = response.css("span.product-pricing__main-price::text").extract()

list(filter(lambda pre:pre !='', product_price_euros))

Im not sure I do it right, i've still empty values..

Comment: Actually i'm not sure that it detects that the item is empty... When I try to remove it when iterating through the list it doesn't change the result

Comment: No, just collect all the values and in the end filter the result you get