# Scrapy get result in shell but not in script

Tags: python, scrapy

one topic again ^^ Based on recommendations here, I've implemented my bot the following and tested it all in shell :

```
    name_list = response.css("h2.label.title::text").extract()
    packaging_list = response.css("div.label.packaging::text").extract()
    ean = response.css("h1.page-title::text").extract_first()
    product_price = ''.join(response.css('.product-pricing__main-price  ::text').extract())
    company = "carrefour"

    for name, packaging, price in zip(name_list, packaging_list, product_price):
        item = ScrapybotItem()
        item['ean'] = ean
        item['desc'] = name.replace("\n","").strip() + " " +  packaging
        item['price'] = price
        item['company'] = company

        yield item
```

Problem is with price field.

For price in shell, I have for instance :

```
In [2]: product_price
Out[2]: '\n                    5,65€\n\n  \n      '
```

Output from script for same product :

```
{'company': 'carrefour',
'desc': "Gel nettoyant anti-imperfections 5 en 1 L'Oréal Paris Men Expert 
 le "
     'tube de 150ml',
 'ean': '\n  1 résultat pour « 3600522418634 »\n',
 'price': '\n'}
```

Do you know why don't I get result for prices with script ?

Answer (score 1):

`product_price` is a string, given that you are joining the results of the selector in:

```
product_price = ''.join(response.css('.product-pricing__main-price  ::text').extract())
```

Then, when you use `zip`, you'll be splitting that string in parts, thus you'll have the `\n` for the first item, as it's probably the first character in `product_price`.

Check this example:

```
>>> for i, j, k in zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 'abcd'):
        print (i, j, k)
```

Output:

```
1 5 a
2 6 b
3 7 c
4 8 d
```

Comment: Ok I understand better now ! But how do you keep product_price result in this case ?

Comment: Is the price a single element?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by single ^^ but with response.css('.product-pricing__main-price  ::text').extract()  i get something like  '\n                    1',
 ',62€',
 '\n\n  \n      ',

Comment: actually i would like to have like 1,62. If there is several prices, such as for instance  '\n 1', ',62€', '\n\n \n ', '\n 1', ',58€', '\n\n \n '
it would be 1,62 and 1,58